# Using debounce with React hooks causes endless requests

Tags: reactjs

I need to get data from server on changes in search input but I don't want to send a new request on every new character there so I'm trying use `debounce` from `use-debounce` package https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce. But my code below causes only endless requests before even any changes in search input happens.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { useDebounce } from "use-debounce";
import { Layout } from "./../Layout";
import { List } from "./../List";
import { Loader } from "./../Loader";
import { Header } from "./../Header";
import { Search } from "./../Search";
import { Licenses } from "./../Licenses";
import { Pagination } from "./../Pagination";

import "./App.css";

const PER_PAGE = 20;

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [nameSearch, setNameSearch] = useState("");
  const [license, setLicense] = useState({});
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const debouncedNameSearch = useDebounce(nameSearch, 2000);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setHasError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const prevMonth = moment()
        .subtract(30, "days")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      const licenseKey = (license && license.key) || "";

      const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${nameSearch}+in:name+language:javascript+created:${prevMonth}${
        licenseKey ? `+license:${licenseKey}` : ""
      }&sort=stars&order=desc&page=${currentPage}&per_page=${PER_PAGE}`;

      const response = await axios(url);
      setData(response.data.items);
      setTotal(response.data.total_count);
    } catch (error) {
      setHasError(true);
      setData([]);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [license, nameSearch, currentPage]);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header>
        <Search
          handleNameSearchChange={setNameSearch}
          nameSearch={nameSearch}
        />
        <Licenses license={license} handleLicenseChange={setLicense} />
      </Header>

      <main>
        {hasError && <div>Error...</div>}

        {isLoading && <Loader />}

        {data && !isLoading && !hasError && (
          <>
            <List data={data} />
            <Pagination
              currentPage={currentPage}
              total={total}
              itemsPerPage={PER_PAGE}
              handlePageChange={setCurrentPage}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

**Search.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const Search = ({ handleNameSearchChange, nameSearch }) => (
  <div className="flex-grow-1 mx-lg-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="search"
      placeholder="Enter name..."
      onChange={e => handleNameSearchChange(e.target.value)}
      className="form-control"
      value={nameSearch}
    />
  </div>
);

Search.propTypes = {
  nameSearch: PropTypes.string,
  handleNameSearchChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

How to make debounce work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never refer to `debouncedNameSearch`.

I think the issue is with your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [license, nameSearch, currentPage]);
```

The first issue is that it will fire every time `nameSearch` changes, so you should change it to use `debouncedNameSearch`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [license, debouncedNameSearch, currentPage]);
```

---

You are also firing the request on initial render when `debouncedNameSearch` is an empty `string`, so you could wrap the call to `fetchData` in a conditional to prevent the request firing when `debouncedNameSearch === ""`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(debouncedNameSearch) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [license, debouncedNameSearch, currentPage]);
```

---

Also, your request is using `nameSearch` when it should be using `debouncedNameSearch`:

```
const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${nameSearch}...
```

Change to:

```
const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${debouncedNameSearch}...
```

---

And it's recommended that any function that is declared inside a component and called inside a `useEffect` should either be declared inside the `useEffect`, or set as a dependency of that `useEffect`:

Read the docs: [is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

So you can either do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Declare fetchData inside useEffect
  const fetchData = async () => {...};

  if (debouncedNameSearch) {
    // Call it inside useEffect too
    fetchData();
  }
}, [
  // Don't forget to add the function's dependencies
  license,
  debouncedNameSearch,
  currentPage,
  setHasError,
  setIsLoading,
  setData,
  setTotal
]);
```

Or you can make the function itself a dependency of the `useEffect`, but you should wrap the function in a `useCallback` to make sure its state dependencies are up to date (as per the documentation linked above):

```
const fetchData = useCallback(
  async () => {
    // Function defined here
  },
  [ // function dependencies
    setHasError,
    setIsLoading,
    license,
    debouncedNameSearch,
    currentPage,
    setData,
    setTotal,
    setHasError
  ]
);

useEffect(() => {
  if(debouncedNameSearch) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [license, debouncedNameSearch, currentPage, fetchData]); // Add as dependency
```